# Convert a'+b(a+b')(b+c') to sum of products and product of sums using boolean algebra.

Tags: boolean-algebra

Sum of products

```
F = a'+b(a+b')(b+c')
  = a'+ ab + bb' (b+c')
  = a'+ab
```

So that's about as far as I've gotten. I'm trying to find a step by step guide on how to do these sorts of problems but still unclear as to how. Any sort of directions would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you do with the term (b+c')? I can't quite get if you want to multiply it or add it.

Comment: I thought bb' evaluates to 0 and 0 and anything can be disregarded?

Comment: Yeah that's okay but what I was talking about was that you didn't multiply the term $ab$ with $(b+c')$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a good summary of the laws of boolean algebra at http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/. Note that their notation uses $\overline{A}$ instead of $A'$ for the NOT operator.

Then $F$ can be reduced to a much simpler form:

$$\begin{align}
F &= a'+b(a+b')(b+c') \\
  &= a'+(ba+bb')(b+c') &(\text{distributive law}) \\
  &= a'+(ab+0)(b+c') &(\text{commutative law, redundance law (T9)}) \\
  &= a'+ab(b+c') &(\text{redundance law (T7)}) \\
  &= a'+abb+abc' &(\text{distributive law}) \\
  &= a'+ab+abc' &(\text{redundance law (T6)}) \\
  &= a'+ab(1+c') &(\text{distributive law}) \\
  &= a'+ab &(\text{redundance law (T8)}) \\
  &= a'+b &(\text{redundance law (T10)}) \\
\end{align}$$